# How to compile and install change to Ubuntu Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, updates, compiling

Short version:
How do I make a change to the Ubuntu Linux kernel (18.04 LTS), compile it, install it, and use it on subsequent boot up's?

Long version:
There seems to be an issue with the Trim function not working properly under Linux with the newest Ryzen platforms.  A work-around/fix for this issue was identified at Kernel.org - Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202665) where one must update a line of code at 'drivers/nvme/host/core.c' must be modified.

What I've done so far:

I found the following article Build your own Kernel article on Ubuntu's site (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).
I have also downloaded the Ubuntu source using the git command specified in the Ubuntu article.  I was able to find the `drivers/nvme/host/core.c` that needed to be updated and I made the appropriate change.

Aside from making sure the packages/dependencies are installed on my system to build a new kernel (as outlined in the Ubuntu article), the only thing that needs to be done is run the following commands:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
# quicker build:
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
# if you need linux-tools or lowlatency kernel, run instead:
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

`sudo dpkg -i linux*4.8.0-17.19*.deb`  (I realize 4.8.0-17.19 won't be the filename I'll see for the latest version of 18.04 LTS)

...but aside form this, is there anything else I need to do?  I plan to test this out in a VM first.

Thank you for confirming or filling me in on anything I might be overlooking